# JS/CSS Clip Path - How to calculate radius for circle?

Tags: javascript, css, geometry, clip-path

I'm trying to dynamically set the radius for `clip-path: circle(radius)` so that it fit's within whatever size container it's in (with a bit of extra space around it). For example, if the container is 1000x500, then the entire circle should be 2/3rds of 500px.

I've tried setting the radius to a simple percentage such as 33%, which should make the full circle 2/3rds but depending on the size of the container it can either be too big or too small.

Looking at the documentation for basic shapes, the percentage for radius is resolved from the width and height of the containing box, `sqrt(width^2+height^2)/sqrt(2)` but I have no idea how to actually use that to make the calculation.

Does anybody know what I can do? I'm animating these values so I do need it to be done via `clip-path`.

Comment: It's basically about finding a geometric average of width and height; the above formula is the side length of a square that has the same diagonal as the rectangle. However that formula is useless to you anyway because you want the smaller of the two sides to determine the size of the clipping circle so it's always fully inside the container. Which means you need `Math.min(width, height) / 3` to get the radius in pixels.

Comment: If your container is the size of your screen you could just [`vmin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) instead of percentage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same with `mask` and without any calculation

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800) center/cover no-repeat;

  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#fff 99%,transparent 100%);
          mask:radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#fff 99%,transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="width:200px;height:100px"></div>

<div class="box" style="width:100px;height:200px"></div>

<div class="box" style="width:300px;height:300px"></div>
```

To illustrate how it works:

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  border:2px solid;
  background:
     radial-gradient(circle closest-side,transparent 99%,red 100%),
     url(https://picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800) center/cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="width:200px;height:100px"></div>

<div class="box" style="width:100px;height:200px"></div>

<div class="box" style="width:300px;height:300px"></div>
```

---

You can also add animation:

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800) center/cover no-repeat;

  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#fff 99%,transparent 100%) center/100% 100% no-repeat;
          mask:radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#fff 99%,transparent 100%) center/100% 100% no-repeat;
   transition:0.5s;
}
.box:hover {
   -webkit-mask-size:0% 0%;
           mask-size:0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="width:300px;height:300px"></div>
<div class="box" style="width:200px;height:100px"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry I should mention I'm actually animating the circle so I do need it to be done via `clip-path`

Comment: @KeironLowe you can also animate mask the same way you do with clip-path